# Double toolbar trouble

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar

i have a problem about toolbar. i have 2 fragment and 1 activity. I have a toolbar in activity and i want to change the toolbar when we go to the second fragment. The problem is i can't replace my toolbar on activity even i've already setsupportactionbar in my second fragment.

Double Toolbar Image

[image]

Here is my second fragment xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detailimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

and here is my second fragment activity code:

```
AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
        appCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Second Fragment");
```

Btw, I already to hide and it works, but if i press back to my first fragment, the activity toolbar doesn't show up even though i've already define showtoolbar onstop method

Comment: Instead of setting up new `Toolbar`, call toolbar of activity on fragment and set it up. It will work.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg so, i need to make the collapsingtoolbarlayout on activity not my fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Theme with Parent NoActionBar in The Activity.

And Use `getSupportActionBar()` to inflate ActionBar in The Activity.

By Using this when You call the Fragment that will Chnage the Title of the Action bar to SecondFragment without any 2nd ActionBar

Comment: Do you mean use getSupportActionBar().setCustomView ? btw, I don't want to just change the title, but i want to change the toolbar to collapsing toolbar layout.